# shiny for python: maxRequestSize

Tags: python, py-shiny

I'm building a shiny app in python. I'd like to keep this deployment without R if possible and I need to be able to upload large files (30 to 50 MB). In R, I'd simply set the option maxRequestSize to the desired value afaik.

However, I'm not able to find anything about how to raise this limit in python.
I'd be very thankful for any help!

Comment: I can't see anything in the docs. What happens when you try and upload the files?

Comment: @smartse there appears following error message "<html> <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head> <body> <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center> </" right under the input field, where the progress bar is supposed to be

Comment: I haven't tried this and not sure it's what you need but how about setting `ws_max_size=` in `run_app`? https://shiny.posit.co/py/api/run_app.html

Comment: @smartse changing ws_max_size doesn't have any effect on this. The default limit seems to be 1MB by the way, since the upload of any file larger than 1 MB leads to this error.

Comment: Well that's annoying! Probably time to open an issue then https://github.com/posit-dev/py-shiny/issues

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the VM I'm developing on and the limit probably has nothing to do with shiny or python. Not sure how to change this in my setup, but once I dockerized the app and deployed it, it's possible to upload larger files.